# Spring Boot Microservice cant connect to Eureka Server

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I try to connect my service (auth-service) to the Eureka Server for the service registry. The Eureka server is running, but when I try to connect the auth-service nothing happens.

I added the configurations to application.yaml and application.properties, but nothing helped.

application.yaml from auth-service:

```
eureka:
      client:
        fetchRegistry: true
        registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
      instance:
        preferIpAddress: true
```

URL of Eureka server: http://localhost:8761/

DS Replicas: localhost

Message when I start auth-service:

```
2019-05-24 16:58:11.457  INFO [auth-service,,,] 14704 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-24 16:58:13.293  INFO [auth-service,,,] 14704 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2019-05-24 16:58:14.521  INFO [auth-service,,,] 14704 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-05-24 16:58:14.524  INFO [auth-service,,,] 14704 --- [           main] d.h.authservice.AuthServiceApplication   : Started AuthServiceApplication in 11.448 seconds (JVM running for 12.63)
```

The Eureka Server is annotated with @EnableEurekaServer and the Client is annotated with @EnableDiscoveryClient

auth-service pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>de.hspf</groupId>
<artifactId>auth-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>auth-service</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.M9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Discovery Service pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>discovery-server</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>

            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>

            <version>Finchley.M9</version>

            <type>pom</type>

            <scope>import</scope>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: What's versions are you using? Can you post dependencies (build files)?

Comment: I just added the pom files of the discovery server and auth-service

Comment: While you have `spring-cloud.version`, you aren't using that property and setting the version to `<version>Finchley.M9</version>` which is an unsupported milestone. Please change it to Greenwich.SR1 (the latest) and update boot to 2.1.5 and try again.

Comment: I changed the version settings in the properties section and the dependency management to Greenwich.SR1 and Spring boot to 2.1.5, but still nothing happens. The Eureka Server is running but not showing any registered service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this dependency for client

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Default settings should be :

```
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

As suggested by the official site.
Also, Don't forget to add @EnableEurekaServer in your main file
Source: https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

Answer (score 0):

In the auth-service application.yaml is missing: `registerWithEureka: true`

```
eureka:
      client:
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
      instance:
        preferIpAddress: true
```

You just put the `fetchRegistry: true`, which is used to record information on the client obtained from the server, to find other microservices, but not to register the client.

Comment: I added this code to my application.yaml, but still nothing happens

Comment: http://localhost:8761/eureka/ Replica is unavailable and not ind the available section of the Eureka Dashbaord. Maybe this is a an issue?

Comment: Put your configuration of eureka server. Is the server up and can you acces to http://localhost:8761 ??